# Aharonov–Bohm effect on a non-contractible manifold

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

The [Aharonov–Bohm effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) shows the vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ is more fundamental than magnetic flux density $\mathbf{B}$. However, vector potential is introduced by
$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B} $$ or $$ \mathrm{d}  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}  $$
which requires the Poincaré's lemma to ensure the existence of $\mathbf{A}$. If the manifold is not contractible, there is no guarantee that $\mathbf{A}$ exists. On a non-contractible manifold, what would happen for the Aharonov–Bohm effect?

Comment: $\mathbf{B}$ is "magnetic flux density", not "magnetic potential"...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76760/2451

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition for $dB = 0$ (more commonly written $\nabla \cdot \mathbf B = 0$) to imply $B = dA$ is the vanishing of the second de Rham cohomology $H^2 (M)$. This is guaranteed for a contractible manifold since cohomology is homotopy invariant. However this is for a 2-form $B$ defined on *all of* $M$. Consider instead the restriction of $B$ to some open set $U$, $B|_U$. We can take $U$ to be contractible, for instance, $U$ could be the image of a coordinate ball. Then $H^2(U)$ vanishes and we can find $A_U$ such that on $U$, $dA_u = B|_U$. Therefore there always exists a *local* vector potential.

The Aharonov-Bohm effect is related to the nonvanishing of $$\Phi = \oint A$$
even when $dA = 0$. When the first de Rham cohomology $H^1(M)$ vanishes, we have that $dA = 0$ is equivalent to $A = df$, and so by Stokes's theorem $\Phi$ is always $0$. In particular $\Phi$ can never be non-zero for a contractible space.

When a global $A$ cannot be found, one can still make sense of the quantity $\Phi$, but the best way to do this is with the tools of gauge theory. The book *Gauge Fields, Knots, and Gravity* by Baez and Muniain discusses much of the concepts mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Can you give a non-trivial example when both $H^1$ and $H^2$ are non-vanishing? Thanks for the book btw.

Comment: Is a torus $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ non-trivial enough?

Comment: Torus will do, thanks :-) So, in our physical $R^3$ space this example coiuld be implemented as two deleted rings, linked as chain links, right? Is it of any interest to reproduce the Aharonov-Bohm-like experiment for such configuration of solenoids?

Answer (score 8):

Formal accounts of EM do not need the Poincare lemma for the vector potential to exist:

Formulating a theory like electromagnetism on any manifold is best done by viewing it as the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ [gauge theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory) on said manifold. Then, the "vector potential" is simply a connection on the circle bundle over the manifold, which exists regardless of whether Poincare holds or not. The electric and magnetic fields are then components of the curvature tensor $F = \mathrm{d}A$, just as in the [covariant formulation of EM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism).

The Aharanov-Bohm effect essentially already takes place on a non-contractible manifold, since the usual arrangement removes an entire line from the manifold considered where the solenoid is. And $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a line removed is a cylinder, and not contractible. (see also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123423/basic-question-on-the-aharonov-bohm-effect))

Comment: So the answer is, $\mathbf{A}$ is defined locally?

Comment: @user26143: That is one way of interpreting it, yes. It *is* globally defined on the principal bundle over the manifold, but projects down onto the manifold itself only locally, and the different local $A$ are related by gauge transformations. (The procedure of gluing the local forms by gauge transformations can also be understood as defining the principal bundle)